# Bash check if file exists on startup

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a BASH script on a Debian machine. The script should run on every startup (so I put the `.sh` file in `/etc/init.d`) if the mac address I previously copied to a hidden `.mac.txt` file matches with the actual MAC address of the machine or if the `.mac.txt` file exists than the machine should start. If either one of the conditions is not true than the machine should shutdown.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="'cat /root/.mac.txt'";
mac="'/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'eth0' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5'"
if ["$mac" = "$output" ] || [ -f /root/.mac.txt]
then
echo "Server will start"
else
shutdown -h now
fi
```

If the mac address is incorrect the machine shuts down, but if I remove the `.mac.txt` file it does not. Am I making some logic or syntax error?

Comment: In addition to FatalError's point about spaces around `[` and `]` -- 1. I don't understand your logic. If they're equal, then the file must exist. So why bother checking if they're equal at all? Why not just check if the file exists? 2. You seem to have confused `'` with `\``. The statement `output="'cay /root/.mac.txt'"`, for example, will set the variable `$output` equal to the string `'cay /root/.mac.txt'`, rather than running any sort of command. 3. Did you mean `cat` rather than `cay`?

Comment: A script does not automatically run at startup just because it is in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: i think what i want to do is this : first i want to check if the .mac.txt file exists.If it doesn't exist shutdown machine. If it exists than it should check if the mac addresses match. If they don't shut down machine..if they match than continue with the startup

Comment: @chepner i gave the file executable permissions if that is what you are referring to

Comment: No, I mean files in `/etc/init.d` are not executed unless they are explicitly executed from somewhere else (such as, depending on the setup of your machine, `/etc/rc`). Just adding a file to that directory does not cause it to be executed.

Comment: @chepner ohh wow i'm kind of shocked that's what i read on many sites i thought all you have to do is put it in init.d..i tried putting it in rc.2 as S19mcscrip.sh but still no luck

Comment: Why did this get down votes?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modified version:

```
#!/bin/bash
macfile='/root/.mac.txt'
mac=$(/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'eth0' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5)

# Shut down if file does not exist
if [ ! -f $macfile ]; then
    shutdown -h now
fi

# Verify MAC address against cached value
output=$(cat $macfile)
if [ "$mac" = "$output" ]; then
    echo "Server will start" 
else 
    shutdown -h now 
fi
```

Explanation:

- Test for the existence of the file *before* you read from it
- The "`[`" and "`]`" characters must have a whitespace before and after them
- When running sub-commands, use the `$( ... )` syntax instead of backticks

Comment: i don't know why but the script is still not working i gave it executable permissions but it wont work on the startup..if the machine is on though it does work..

Comment: @Aaron- What do you mean by "not working"?  What specifically is it doing, and what did you expect it to do?  Does it work if you run it manually instead of automatically?  Are you certain that it's running at all?

Comment: Never mind all i had to do is run the update-rc.d command..thnk you for your help!