# Bash check if file exists on startup

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash check if file exists on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476563/bash-check-if-file-exists-on-startup)

I am trying to run a BASH script on a Debian machine. The script should run on every startup (so I put the `.sh` file in `/etc/init.d`) if the mac address I previously copied to a hidden `.mac.txt` file matches with the actual MAC address of the machine or if the `.mac.txt` file exists the machine can start. If either one of the conditions is not true the machine should shut down.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="'cat /root/.mac.txt'";
mac="'/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'eth0' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5'"
if ["$mac" = "$output" ] || [ -f /root/.mac.txt]
then
echo "Server will start"
else
shutdown -h now
fi
```

If the mac address is incorrect the machine shuts down, but if I remove the `.mac.txt` file it does not. Am I making some logic or syntax error?

Comment: You might try '-e' instead of '-f'. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: Single quotes instead of backticks, `cay` instead of `cat` … this code won’t work at all.

Comment: yes this is my first bash program i'm sorry i'm not very familiar with linu anyways without the || [ -f /root/.mac.txt] the script works just fine ..just wondering how to add that..that's all

Comment: @Aaron what is *linu*, take more time and attention to detail to what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a logical or (`||`), change that to an and (`&&`) and it should work.

Comment: No, the “or” is one of the very few correct things in that code.

Comment: Aaron said: "If either one of the conditions is not true the machine should shut down." or conversely the file should exist **and** have the correct mac address.

Comment: ...which contradicts the previous sentence.  The English description doesn't work either.

Comment: @Thor “either … or” is not the same as “and”, on the contrary.

Comment: Both are preceded by not so what he is saying is if !A || !B the server should shut down; but in the code this is the `else` clause, so the `if` is actually !(!A || !B) which is the same as A && B. [Truth table](http://pastebin.com/cXgm3D1K).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your spacing. Bash is VERY particular on white space. I just tested on my server and it works this way:

```
if [ "$mac" = "$output" ] || [ -f /root/.mac.txt ]
...
```

You need an extra space between `[` and `"$mac"` and another between `.txt` and `]`

Comment: For the curious, this isn't bash being particular about the whitespace - `[` is actually the name of a program, and it's being combined with `$mac`.  It's like trying to run `firefox google.com` by typing `firefoxgoogle.com`.